# sleekxmpp 'error reading from xml stream' connected <--> disconnected loop

Tags: python, xml, django, xmpp, google-talk

I am on the develop branch.

I modified `EchoBot` just a little bit, below is the changed/added code, otherwise I took the rest from the example included with the source:

```
self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)
self.add_event_handler("changed_status", self.change)
...

def start(self, event):
    self.send_presence(pshow='xa' , ppriority="0")
    self.get_roster()

def change(self, event):
    #This is django stuff, essentially what I am trying to do is log info from changed_status events
    c = Change(jid = event['from'], timestamp = timezone.now(), new_availability = event['type'], new_priority = event['priority'])
    c.save()
```

I was having trouble getting this to start period for a while, then after a reboot it worked for about an hour then seemingly out of nowhere the same error below occurred. What happens next is basically a loop of getting connected and then another XML stream error causing a disconnect etc...

```
ERROR    Error reading from XML stream.
DEBUG    reconnecting...
DEBUG    SEND (IMMED): 
INFO     Waiting for  from server
DEBUG     ==== TRANSITION connected -> disconnected
DEBUG    connecting...
DEBUG    Waiting 1.84108932156 seconds before connecting.
DEBUG    Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
DEBUG     ==== TRANSITION disconnected -> connected
DEBUG    SEND (IMMED): 
DEBUG    RECV: X-GOOGLE-TOKENX-OAUTH2
DEBUG    SEND (IMMED): 
DEBUG    RECV: 
DEBUG    Starting TLS
INFO     Negotiating TLS
INFO     Using SSL version: 3
```

After this error occurs if I try to run `EchoBot` from `echo_client.py` I get stuck at `connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx`.

If I run my version of `EchoBot` again it begins working properly, but I am worried that other error will occur again.

Possibly relevant:
  * Connecting to Google Talk
  * Also signed in to gmail through my browser
  * Also signed on to Google talk on my Android

My question is how to resolve this error, or what to do to catch it and handle it properly?

Comment: Was this a one time issue, or is this happening consistently?

The "error reading from XML stream" error means that the connection was lost, especially for GTalk since it doesn't tend to send the closing stream element and just terminates the connection. Did you receive a stream error element before the "error reading" log?

At first glance, if this was a one time issue, then it looks like there was just a network issue in reaching a GTalk server.

Also, what do you mean by "having trouble getting this to start period for a while?" Were there other connection issues before this?

Comment: @LanceStout thanks for your comment, I wont be in front of the logs that I have for a while, but you can expect another comment tonight with more detailed answers to your questions. For now I can answer your last question, what I meant by "having trouble getting this to start period..." is that I would try every few minutes to start my EchoBot and a similar (if not the same) error to what is above occurred. After a reboot and some waiting it eventually worked.

Comment: One potential issue may be that you do not have dnspython installed? The default echo_client.py without dnspython will not connect to GTalk without manually modifying the connect() call to use "talk.google.com" as the host to connect instead of "gmail.com"

Comment: I do NOT have it installed, that may have been my issue with trying the default echo_client.py because I did not modify it. When I get to those logs I will also try to use the default client after modifying the connect() call appropriately, and see if I get any issues.

Comment: @LanceStout, I am in front of the logs now.
I just tried to kick off my Echobot and got the same error. I also tried echo_client.py with the added line for using google talk and got the same/a similar error of "error reading from xml stream" and then connecting <--> disconnecting. The only other error I seem to get is a iqtimeout error after a ^C to disconnect